# reading multiple files in R with appropriate headers

Tags: r

I am trying to read multiple files (around 1000 files) in R with the following code:

```
for (i in 1:length(top100.files)) assign(top100.files[i], read.table(top100.files[i]))
```

When i try to do

```
head(top100.files[[1]])
```

I get the first element of the list which is:

```
top.1.file
```

When I try to do `head(top.1.file)`, I get:

```
    V1    V2    V3
1 string Desc  occ
2 xxxxxx Desc1  51
3 xxxxxy Desc2   9
4 xxxxxg Desc3  23
5 xxxxxz Desc4  23
6 xxxxyx Desc5  22
```

As we can see, my actual header (String, desc, occ) has become part of my table.

Could you please help me on how to read multiple files with the appropriate file headers such that we get:

```
  string Desc  occ
1 xxxxxx Desc1  51
2 xxxxxy Desc2   9
3 xxxxxg Desc3  23
4 xxxxxz Desc4  23
5 xxxxyx Desc5  22
```

Comment: `read.table()` takes a `header` argument

Comment: Sorry for not checking prior. it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this here:

```
ll <- lapply(X=top100.files, FUN=read.table, header=TRUE)
```

Comment: What do you mean? It is not working as you need it to?

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me, the headers were perfect but my files were in csv format :

```
setwd("put the path of the directory, where you have kept the files to be read")
    path <- "put the path of the directory, where you have kept the files to be read"
    setwd(path)

    read_multiple<-function(){
      files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv") # for csv files
      df<-NULL
      for (f in files) {
        sdf<-read.csv(file=f)
        if (nrow(sdf)>0){
          df<-rbind(df,sdf)
        }
       }
      return(df)
    }

    ndf <- read_multiple()
    head (ndf)
```